# Transpose rows into columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, transpose

I have data for 2 weeks like this coming out of complicated 'With statement'-

```
DATE        WEEKDAY     CODE
2015/01/05  Monday      A
2015/01/06  Tuesday     A
2015/01/07  Wednesday   P
2015/01/08  Thursday    A
2015/01/09  Friday      P
2015/01/12  Monday      P
2015/01/13  Tuesday     P
2015/01/14  Wednesday   P
2015/01/15  Thursday    P
2015/01/16  Friday      P
```

and I want to transpose into two weeks like this -

```
WEEK        Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday
2015/01/05  A       A       P           A           P
2015/01/12  P       P       P           P           P

With PS_Att_pivot_data AS (--------------)  SELECT * FROM ( SELECT (Case when Weekday ='Monday' then SchoolDay end) AS Week, Weekday, Att_code FROM PS_Att_pivot_data ) PIVOT (max(Att_code) for Weekday in ('Monday', 'Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'))
```

my script is giving results like this -

```
WEEK     'Monday'   'Tuesday'   'Wednesday' 'Thursday'  'Friday'
(null)  (null)       P           P            P          P 
2015/01/12  P         (null)    (null)  (null)  (null)
2015/01/05  A        (null)     (null)  (null)  (null)
```

Please help me with Pivot statement.
Thanks,

Comment: I have following -   With PS_Att_pivot_data AS
(--------------) that gives the data set for all dates and then following to transpose the above data -)
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT (Case when Weekday ='Monday' then SchoolDay end) AS Week, Weekday, Att_code    FROM PS_Att_pivot_data
        )
PIVOT (max(Att_code) for Weekday in ('Monday', 'Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'))

Comment: Please edit you question (with the edit button under the tags) and add your code in your question. It's not readable as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this might be what you're after:

```
with sample_data as (select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Monday' weekday, 'A' code from dual union all
                     select to_date('06/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Tuesday' weekday, 'A' code from dual union all
                     select to_date('07/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Wednesday' weekday, 'P' code from dual union all
                     select to_date('08/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Thursday' weekday, 'A' code from dual union all
                     select to_date('09/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Friday' weekday, 'P' code from dual union all
                     select to_date('12/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Monday' weekday, 'P' code from dual union all
                     select to_date('13/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Tuesday' weekday, 'P' code from dual union all
                     select to_date('14/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Wednesday' weekday, 'P' code from dual union all
                     select to_date('15/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Thursday' weekday, 'P' code from dual union all
                     select to_date('16/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Friday' weekday, 'P' code from dual)
-- end of mimicking your data in a table called sample_data
select *
from   (select trunc(dt, 'iw') week_start_dt,
               weekday,
               code
        from   sample_data) 
pivot  (max(code) for weekday in ('Monday' as monday, 
                                  'Tuesday' as tuesday,
                                  'Wednesday' as wednesday,
                                  'Thursday' as thursday,
                                  'Friday' as friday))
order by week_start_dt;

WEEK_START_DT MONDAY TUESDAY WEDNESDAY THURSDAY FRIDAY
------------- ------ ------- --------- -------- ------
2015/01/05    A      A       P         A        P     
2015/01/12    P      P       P         P        P
```

I sincerely hope that `WEEKDAY` is derived from the dt column in your real code!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! When I run your script; it works perfect. Yes, weekday is derived from the real date in my data.